# How to detect when click inside elements using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

https://jsfiddle.net/r1x8gyha/1/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
$(function() {
    $("body").click(function(e) {
        if (e.target.id == "xxx") { 
            alert("Inside div");
        }
    });
})
});
</script>

<div id="xxx" style="background: red;">
<iframe width="420" height="315"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JGwWNGJdvx8">
</iframe>
</div>
```

When click inside iframe for play video. why jacascript not alert ?

(iframe is inside elements id `xxx`)

Comment: The frame content is on a remote domain, so you cannot receive events from it. What you're trying to do isn't possible.

Comment: please advice me. how can i do ?

Comment: That's the point, you can't. In terms of browser security, this is a very, *very* good thing.

Comment: It's possible with `postMessage`, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17816373/javascript-iframe-resizing-using-postmessage-method

Comment: change " $("body").click(function(e) { " to $("iframe").click(function(e) {

Comment: let me if this helps?