# Bypass Cross-Domain-Policy to access iframe's HTML with server-side solution

Tags: javascript, php, html

Currently we are trying to access the HTML of (with javascript) dynamically generated html-elements (e.g. to get the url of an image). If the html-elements are generated with javascript only - their is no problem. Just extracting the image url with javascript by accessing the DOM elements. But now we have trouble with an iframe.

This is the situation at the moment:

- We include external script-file *(www.test.com/script.js)* to create a gallery on our website
- The script.js generates a new iframe in our website *(document.write('iframe code here')); referencing to www.test.com/iframe.html)*
- The iframe.html contains javascript-code again to generate the gallery by creating serveral dom-elements (divs, imgs, a, p,....)

Now we need to read the src-attribute of these images. With the debugging tool of the browser, it is no problem. Without the iframe, it's also no problem. But with the iframe, because of the cross domain policy of the browsers we can not access the html of the iframe.html with javascript.

**One possible solution** was to try to get the src of the iframe tag with javascript, call a server-side script to get the html content of the src-url and run the content via eval()-function on the client again.

I hope you have other better ways to solve that.

Comment: Only way that does not involve magic (the stuff that does not work on all browsers and breaks every other week) is to use a headless browser on the server. Try phantomjs for example. It's like doing a cURL request but also executes all the JS like a browser does so you get the "final" HTML.

Comment: Do you have access to the server where you are trying to get the content from?

Comment: Sergiu Paraschiv, i think thats the best way and is a Solution i am looking for!

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your question, but if the iframe is being served by your app, you can [use postMessage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800309/using-postmessage-to-refresh-iframes-parent-document) in order to communicate between the iframe and its parent window.