# How to resize an iframe (HTTPS) from a site (HTTP) under the same domain

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a site that host some public content:  `https://secure.example.com/PublicContent.html`.  I am rendering it through an iframe on an unsecured site:  `http://public.example.com`.  I have both pages setting `document.domain = "example.com";`.

If I load `public.example.com` using HTTPS, I can have the iframe resize correctly using the `onload` attribute:

```
onload="this.style.height = this.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';"
```

However, if I load `public.example.com` without HTTPS, I get `Access is denied.`  Any ideas how to get this to work on HTTP?

Comment: Did you try using: `<iframe src="//public.example.com" >` ?

Comment: @PedroBaptistaAfonso:  The src is `https://secure.example.com/PublicContent.html`.  Removing the `https:` doesn't get around the issue.  (The secure site also can't be loaded over HTTP; HTTPS is enforced.)

Comment: Did you try the **postMessage()** technique?  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800309/using-postmessage-to-refresh-iframes-parent-document

Comment: @JonSG:  That was simple and worked!  Can you post as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Not possible if you're using `this.contentWindow`

Same-origin policy: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

> Two pages have the same origin if the protocol, port (if one is specified), and host are the same for both pages.

To share information between the same domain no matter which protocol used, you might want to take a look at cookies. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Cross-origin_data_storage_access.

Also, used this lib to solve a similar issue: https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer

Comment: I'm not sure a cookie would help, since that would have to be submitted to the page, wouldn't it?  And the request to the page would have already been sent before the iframe got triggered (since the response is what triggers the iframe).